# macOS doesn't run executable file anymore, after upgrade to Catalina/Monterey

Tags: macos, applications, bash, script, monterey

Since I upgraded to Monterey (from Mojave), I cannot run anymore a local server that was installed under /Applications.

The app has no extension, the file type is "Unix Executable File". It was working perfectly before the update.

Now when I try to run it from shell it fails with

> -bash: ./ManicTimeServer: `cannot execute binary file`

What's going on? Why the app doesn't run anymore?

And, mainly, **how do I make it run again?**

---

#### Additional info:

- `ls -la ManicTimeServer` returns `-rwxr-xr-x@` (not the additional `xattr`)
- `xattr ManicTimeServer` returns

> com.apple.lastuseddate#PS

- `stat ManicTimeServer` returns

> 16777220 96934799 -rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername staff 0 138736 "Nov 30 17:37:52 2021" "Sep 22 09:26:35 2021" "Nov 30 17:38:24 2021" "Sep 22 09:26:35 2021" 4096 272 0 ManicTimeServer

- `file ManicTimeServer` returns
  ManicTimeServer: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=1cfaaf19b37c906e12f121854b3a6b45c6c9bdf7, stripped
- `otool -L ManicTimeServer` returns

> ManicTimeServer: is not an object file

Comment: Did you checked the file permissions ? ( ls -l ./ManicTimeServer ). You should get something like -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: All good: `-rwxr-xr-x@`; not different from the past. The macOS upgrade didn't provoke changes in filesystem permissions.

Comment: If this is a 32bit app, it will not run under Monterey. Go back to the vendor and see if there is an update.

Comment: Is this about https://www.manictime.com/teams/download ?

Comment: @nohillside yes, exactly, the Linux version. I couldn't find requirements info about 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: How do you want to run the Linux version on macOS?

Comment: The same way I was running it on Mojave: I configured a daemon (via `.plist` and `sudo launchctl start /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.ManicTime.server.start.plist`), that executed the `./ManicTimeServer` CLI command and restarted it in case of crash.

Comment: Any chance you can ask support if you need to uograde? https://www.manictime.com/Teams/How-To-Install-linux-mac seems .NET core may need an update, too for Monterey in some cases

Comment: Yes, thanks for the suggestion. I wrote them yesterday, am waiting for an answer after the weekend. I also reinstalled the Dot.Net SDK, but doesn't seem to help running an already compiled binary (I hoped it would provide the correct interpreter).

Comment: As far as I understand this, you either need Docker to run the Linux x86_64 binary, or .NET to run the Windows DLL

Comment: As stated by others docker should be the best solution. Do not forget docker to use only minimum resources (not the default)

Comment: Usually Docker on Mac uses an amount of resources I'm not comfortable with, for a running a small daemon. – What you mean with "not the default"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a Linux binary, it will not run on macOS.

Comment: [Setting that up in docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/manictime/manictimeserver/) seems to be documented and here conflicts the main page https://www.manictime.com/Teams/How-To-Install-linux-mac, but that doesn’t match OP details for what got installed. Maybe a fresh download or chat with their support is next?

Comment: I would go for the Docker solution, if MacOS supported containers and it didn't require a whole virtual machine running. Docker steals a considerable part of my CPU and RAM; not worth it for running such a little daemon service. – I hoped to keep running the server on the laptop, as in the past, so it is always reachable even when travelling and having no internet available.

Answer (score 0):

The following commands might help to understand the reason of the issue.

For instance for /usr/bin/curl it shows what type the binary is, if it is runnable binary. Additional info regarding binary file types can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/724301/how-to-solve-bash-cannot-execute-binary-file)

% **file /usr/bin/curl**

```
/usr/bin/curl: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64] [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
/usr/bin/curl (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/curl (for architecture arm64e):    Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
```

This command will give details about the file itself. Your comment shows "@" sign after common permission flags, which means that there are extended attributes assigned. I would check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-os-x) thread to verify/update attributes.

% **stat /usr/bin/curl**

```
16777220 1152921500312765277 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 0 406336 "Jan  1 10:00:00 2020" "Jan  1 10:00:00 2020" "Jan  1 10:00:00 2020" "Jan  1 10:00:00 2020" 4096 448 0x80020 /usr/bin/curl
```

The following command will show if there are libraries are missing for the application.

% **otool -L /usr/bin/curl**

```
/usr/bin/curl:
    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.120.1)
```

**Update 1**: according to the output provided the file you are trying to run IS Linux binary, you can see it from the library that is used in the binary "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2". Are you absolutely sure this is the same application that was running cause it appears that someone did a magic that Mac OS accepting Linux binaries or there was some kind of virtual machine wrapper or something similar. Generally running Linux binary with MacOS is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise trying to run the `ManicTimeServer.dll` file instead - as the `ManicTimeServer` executable is only a small stub for Linux that checks whether you have .NET Core installed or not - and then executes from the DLL file.

I.e. try running something like:

```
dotnet ./ManicTimeServer.dll
```

or:

```
mono ./ManicTimeServer.dll
```